# How do I sum values for the previous 12 months, starting from the last month in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

**I'd like to sum the number of leavers in a company in the last 12 months, starting from the previous month to date, in power bi.**

I started with the formula below, however the formula starts counting from today's date. How do I adapt the formula so that it starts summing leavers from the previous month?

`# Of Leavers In The Last 12 Months = calculate(sumX(Values('Calendar'[Month]) , [Leavers]),DATESINPERIOD('Calendar'[Date],MAX('Calendar'[Date]),-12,MONTH))`

Answer (score 1):

It preety simple solution where you first find the current month by creating calculated column in your fact table code snippets attached below.

```
CurrentMonth = 
 var cals = FORMAT(TODAY(),"MMM-YY")
 Return
 IF(FORMAT([Date],"MMM-YY") = cals,"Current Month","")
```

Second step include formula than will calculate last 12 month till end of previous month through measure.

```
Leavers = calculate(SUM('Company Leaver'[Leaver]),'Company Leaver'[CurrentMonth] = BLANK(),DATESINPERIOD('Calendar'[Date], MAX('Calendar'[Date]) - DAY(TODAY()),-13,MONTH))
```

I created dummy dataset example that i linked in form of images hope it help you

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! Could you explain  what [Data] is within your code for ‘current month’ though? Is that a column? I’m asking because I don’t have a [Data] column in my data

Comment: Date column is particularly date information inform of standard date e.g(12-Sep-2023). once you have that column you can apply first step and later create a measure for second steps.

Comment: Okay, so do I have to create a column field? And if so how do i do that?

Comment: By adding the calculated column please give me your email id so i able to send you solution file that i make yesterday

Comment: Sent on your email